# State value in component is updated after the dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a function in a component that adds an entry to my state 1 (in Redux via RTK).

The api returns me the auto-generated id of this new entry and I add it to state 1.

I then need to create an entry in a second state 2 (linked table), using the id of the state 1 entry mentioned above.

My problem is that my state 1 is not directly updated in the component and it is only updated after the entire function has been completed so I don't have access to the id of the new entry of the state 1 at the right moment.

How can I access this new value and especially the id in the function of the component?

**State 1**

```
const spectacles = useAppSelector(spectacleSelector.selectAll);
```

**Function to add an entry in the state 1**

```
const handleCreateClick = () => {
    MySwal.fire({
// not needed code
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            dispatch(createSpectacleAsync(result.value!))
                .then(() => dispatch(createSiteDeTirAsync({ id_Spe: spectacles[spectacles.length - 1]?.id!, code: "C" })))
                .then(() => navigate(`/spectacles/${spectacles[spectacles.length - 1]?.id!}`));
        }
    });
};
```

**Async thunk function to create the entry in the state1**

```
export const createSpectacleAsync = createAsyncThunk<Spectacle, string>(
    'artifices/createSpectacleAsync',
    async (title: any, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            return await agent.Spectacle.createSpectacle({ Titre: title });
        } catch (error: any) {
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({error: error.data})
        }
    }
)
```

**ExtraReducer to manage the new entry returned by the API**

```
builder.addCase(createSpectacleAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    spectacleAdapter.addOne(state, action.payload);
    state.status = 'idle';
});
```